# Exception on using Locale.ENGLISH with a Currency Object

Tags: java

I was wondering why this Java program is throwing an exception when I try to use Locale.ENGLISH with a Currency Object. Can anybody help me??

```
package pr.javautility.TimerAndCurrency;

import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CurrencyDemo {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Currency c;
    c=Currency.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("Symbol used is " + c.getSymbol());
    System.out.println("Default fractional digits "
            + c.getDefaultFractionDigits());
}

}
```

I live in India, by the way.

Comment: what is the exception ??

Comment: Well it would really help us if you'd tell us what the exception is... and get rid of the bits of code which are irrelevant (the comments here...)

Answer (score 3):

```
 c=Currency.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

should be

```
 c=Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK);
```

As per [**Currency#getInstance(Locale) doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)

> Returns the Currency instance for the country of the given locale. IllegalArgumentException - if the country of the given locale is not a
>   supported ISO 3166 country code.

Comment: The exception is an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 2):

The currency must belong to a country:

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK);
```